# Disabling instruction set in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

How to disabling a particular instruction set in VirtualBox?

A modern host computer should have the latest instruction set, such as AVX.

I want to emulate the situation without AVX in the guest OS, so I want to disable AVX instruction set in the VM.

Comment: Haven't played any with VirtualBox, but qemu (and Bochs) allow you to specify the CPU model (somewhat).

Comment: Apparently now is possible, see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/699077/how-to-enable-avx2-extensions-on-a-ubuntu-guest-in-virtualbox-5) on askubuntu.com

Answer (score 2):

VirtualBox does not support that.

If you're running Linux, there exists a patch to remove the features:

"Clear AVX, AVX2 features along with clearing XSAVE feature bits,
as part of the parsing 'noxsave' parameter."
https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/1521191/

Comment: Need to patch and compile kernel? so complicated

Comment: It may be possible to do a symlink hack with /proc/cpuinfo by mounting /proc somewhere else and symlinking everything into /proc except cpuinfo, where you take a file copy and remove the flags by hand. I have no idea if that will work, though. I don't know of a simple way to do this.

Comment: It seems that the patch referenced above made it to the 3.7 Linux release. So if you're running that kernel or later, you should have the patch already, and can invoke the mode by the "noxsave" parameter to the kernel in GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of VirtualBox support this through `VBoxInternal` sets:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ['setextradata', :id, 'VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX', '0']
    vb.customize ['setextradata', :id, 'VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2', '0']
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--ioapic', 'on']
  end
end
```